# Closed set in the uniform topology

Tags: general-topology

For $n \in{} \omega $, define $x^n:=(x_k^n)_k$ of the form $x_k^n=1$ if $k=n$ and $x_k^n=0$ if $k \neq n$. Obviously $x^n \in{} [0,1]^\omega $ for $n \in{} \omega $.

Define $A:=\left\{{x^n: n \in{} \omega}\right\}\subseteq [0,1]^\omega$. I want to prove that A is closed in the uniform topology on $[0,1]^\omega$. I try to prove if A is closed in the product topology on $[0,1]^\omega$, and use the fact that the uniform topology on $[0,1]^\omega$ is finer that the product topology on $[0,1]^\omega$, but I could not do this proof.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't do that is because it's false! This is a good exercise: what's a point in $[0, 1]^\omega$ which is "close to" each $x^n$, but isn't one of the $x^n$s? (Hint: all but one of the $x^n$s begin with "0," all but one of the $x^n$s have second digit "0," all but one of the $x^n$s have third digit "0," . . .)

To show that a set $S$ is closed in the uniform topology, you want to ask, "Which functions can be 'well-approximated' by elements of $S$?" A good first step in solving this question is figuring out why the mystery sequence in the paragraph above is **not** a limit point of $\{x^n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ in the uniform topology.